# Bootstrap 4.1 Caurosel Caption doesn't show in small device

Tags: html, css

This is the code. But the carousel caption part doesn't visible in small device.
Should I use any media query for making it visible? Here I didn't use any css for caption part.I also used max and min height for image. Is it a valid way? How can I make all image same size?

Thanks in advance.

```css
.slider .carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  max-height: 600px;
  min-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider .carousel-inner {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item img {
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/slider/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Caption Header</h5>
          <p>Any Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Caption Header</h5>
          <p>Any Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
          <h5>Caption Header</h5>
          <p>Any Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Check out my answer...

Comment: @PraveenKumar Thank You. It is working.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Done :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of these two [display utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) classes:

```
d-none d-md-block
```

The `d-none` says do not display at all and the `d-md-block` says to display only in medium sized screens. What you need to do is, change medium to small or extra small or totally get rid of `d-none`.

```
d-none d-sm-block
```

Updated snippet:

```css
.slider .carousel-inner {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
  max-height: 600px;
  min-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .slider .carousel-inner {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item {
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .slider .carousel-inner .carousel-item img {
    max-height: 300px;
    min-height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="slider">
  <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/slider/1.jpg" alt="First slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
          <h5>Caption Header</h5>
          <p>Any Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/slider/2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
          <h5>Caption Header</h5>
          <p>Any Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/images/slider/3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-block">
          <h5>Caption Header</h5>
          <p>Any Caption</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</section>
```